# Add hyperlink to PHP form from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I've been trying to get my Email and URL to show up as hyperlinks with a href and mailto with no luck.  Can someone take a look at the following code and let me know what I need to do?  Thanks.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "")  or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("store_location");

    $term = $_POST['term'];

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM store_location 
                        WHERE store_name like '%$term%' 
                        OR address like '%$term%' 
                        OR city like '%$term%' 
                        OR state like '%$term%' 
                        OR zip like '%$term%' 
                        OR phone like '%$term%' 
                        OR fax like '%$term%' 
                        OR email like '%$term%' 
                        OR url like '%$term%' ");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo '<h1>Search Results:</h1>';
      echo 'Store Name: '.$row['store_name'];
      echo '<br/> Address: '.$row['address'];
      echo '<br/> City: '.$row['city'];
      echo '<br/> State: '.$row['state'];
      echo '<br/> Zip: '.$row['zip'];
      echo '<br/> Phone: '.$row['phone'];
      echo '<br/> Fax: '.$row['fax'];
      echo '<br/> Email: '.$row['email'];
      echo '<br/> URL: '.$row['url'];
      echo '<br/><br/>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: I don't even see you trying anything like what you described in your question.  Do you know any HTML?

Answer (score 3):

As your Output is HTML simply write

```
echo '<br/> Email: <a href="mailto:'.$row['email'].'">'.$row['email'].'</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  That worked.  I began learning PHP and MySQL last week and just now created a search box that grabs information from the database.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
echo "<br/><a href='mailto:".$row['email']."'>".$row['email']."</a>"
```

Comment: Double Quotes need more perfomance, and single quotes in HTML does not look nice - OK, we have a duplicate answer! ;)